# Read numbers after equals sign DOS Command Prompt

Tags: text, command-prompt, cmd

In Cmd.exe, how do I keep only the number after an equal sign in a text file?

Input file (input.txt) looks like...
Line1=1.234 
Line2=5.432 
.
.
Line10=3.456

I want the outuput file (output.txt) to look like... 
1.234 
5.432 
.
.
3.456

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `cmd.exe` is not really a programming language. (People sometimes try to use it like one, but it's really obtuse.) Would you consider using a proper programming language for this?

Comment: @Greg, this isn't particularly hard, even in batch files. Also batch files have the advantage of running on any Windows system. WSH can be forbidden with group policies and it happens that you cannot use it, for example. And those are the only two scripting solutions that are universally available on any Windows system from the last decade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
FOR /F "delims== tokens=2" %%a IN (input.txt) DO @ECHO %%a >> output.txt
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the the answer as accepted if you don't need additional feedback, otherwise your question will continue to show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to manipulate the input file in a Batch file.  Here are some tips on string manipulation commands:

http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

Answer (score 0):

With [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm):

```
sed "s/^line[0-9]\+=//g" input.txt > output.txt
```